# Is it possible for a planet to have a noticeable portion of its atmosphere be radon gas?

Tags: planets, atmosphere, radioactivity

Radon Gas is radioactive, and has a half-life of about 3.8 days. It is a decay product of Radium-226, which in turn is a decay product of Uranium-238.

Now there is a planet, let's name it Marvin. Marvin is smaller than mars, at 0.42 Earth Radii, but because of its high density, with a mass of only 0.17 Earth Masses, Marvin has 0.96 Earth Gravities, and an escape velocity of 7.117 Km/s. Marvin has an average surface atmospheric pressure of about 1.33 bars, and 8.3% of that is Radon. Marvin is very volcanically active, so he could be able to vent some radon out in to the atmosphere to always replenish the radon concentrations.

What I am asking is, with enough radioactive materials in the core, could Marvin be able to produce enough radon to keep this concentration of radon gas in the atmosphere?

Comment: Can you say why, please? Who would even Marvin mind?

Answer (score 10):

What we know:

- Planetary radius is 0.42 the Earth's:

  - Volume is 7.4% of Earth's;
  - Surface area is 17.6% of Earth's.
- Mass is 0.17 Earth masses:

  - Average density is 2.3 times Earth's average density, or about 12.6.
  - That's a very high density. Not many metals have densities so high, and none of those are plentiful in the universe. For example, lead, which is usually considered very heavy, has a density of about 11.4. It appears that the planet is made mostly of stuff like rhodium, tantalum, uranium, gold, tungsten, platinum and other such exotics.
- Overall, the small radius is compensated by the very high density, so that in the end the surface gravity is about the same as Earth's; 0.96 *g* is specified in the question.
- Surface atmospheric pressure is 1.3 atm.

What we compute:

- Earth's atmosphere has a mass of about 5.5E18 kg. The fictional planet has a surface area of only 17.6% of Earth's, but the atmospheric pressure on the surface is 1.3 atm; which means that the atmosphere of the planet has a mass of about 0.176 × 1.3 × 0.96 $\approx$ 0.22 of Earth's atmosphere, or 1.2E18 kg.
- 8.3% of the atmosphere is supposed to be radon; that is about 1E17 kg of radon. Radon has a half life of about 4 days, meaning that 1.25E16 kg of radon need to be replenished daily.
- A very large volcanic eruption releases anywhere between 0.5 billion ([Mount St. Helens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1980_eruption_of_Mount_St._Helens) in 1980) and 10 billion tons of ash and lava ([Mount Pinatubo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Pinatubo) in 1991). Let's say that 10% of that mass is radon. (It isn't, and cannot be, but it is a safe generous assumption.) That gives about 1 billion tons, or 1E12 kg, of radon per Mount Pinatubo-class volcanic eruption.
- You would need 10,000 Mount Pinatubo-class volcanic eruptions per day to replenish the radon in the atmosphere.

Are you happy with 10,000 very large volcanic eruptions day after day after day?

<sup>The thermal energy released by the 1980 eruption of Mount St Helens was equivalent to [24 megatons of TNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TNT_equivalent). For comparison, a typical [RSM-56 Bulava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSM-56_Bulava) SLBM carried by the Russian [Borei-class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borei-class_submarine) ballistic missile submarines carries up to 10 warheads each with a maximum yield of 150 kilotons, or 1.5 megatons total. Those tens of thousands of large volcanic eruptions per day would be equivalent to *hundreds of thousands* of nuclear bombs.</sup>

Comment: I don't think vulcanic eruptions are the only source of Radon.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: No they are not, but it is what the question asks for. (And the normal sources of radon are much too feeble to account for the very high concentration required by the question. It is to be assumed that the hypothetical planet has an awful lot of metallic uranium, the decay of which produces radon, which is brought to the surface by volcanoes.)

Comment: Radon gas is very heavy, so you could reasonably assume that it only accumulates in the lowest layers of the atmosphere. On Earth, it accumulates in basements and ground-level rooms. So if 8 % Radon content just in the lowest 5 meters of the atmosphere is fine,you'll need a lot less (I'm not sure about the physics though, likely this will only work if there's no wind).

Answer (score 10):

Such a situation is impossible.

Radon is only produced naturally from Radium. Radium can be chemically extracted and concentrated as a metal at a small scale, but will generate around 400MJ/kg/hour of heat due to radioactive decay.

But Radon decays 154,000 times faster than Radium so an apocalyptic quantity of Radium would be needed to produce such a large quantity of Radon. A large part of the planet would need to be composed of Radium to do this and such vast quantities of Radium would produce enough heat to vaporize and ionize the entire planet.

Comment: Well, actually, as I deduced by doing some math and google searches, it would take around 10^26 kg of radium to keep up with the demand of radon, which is more mass than the planet itself, so in the end, it would not be possible to have that amount of radon in the atmosphere.

Comment: @KaffeeByte I think you made a small calculation error there. Unless I made an error, replenishing 1.45e11 kg/s of Rn-222 should require [this much](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1.45e%2B11+kg%2Fs+*+%28226%2F222%29%2F%28Ra-226+decay+constant%29) Radium which is a mere 1 % of the planet's mass - plenty of room for some normal elements.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem for such a planet is thermal stability: Radon not only decays rapidly but also releases heat in the process. Think of it as a planet-wide reactor core with no ventilation.

250 grams of Radon are going to release ~20 Megawatt Hours of heat daily, if my calculations are correct.

Answer (score 0):

As @AlexP calculated, the atmosphere needs to be replenished with Radon at 1.25e16 kg/day = 1.45e11 kg/s. Let's have a look at all the numbers.

The planet's surface area is around 5.11e14 m^2; for most quantities, it makes sense to consider them per square meter of surface area.

At 1.3 atm pressure, Radon gas has a volume of ~ 7.9e-2 m^3/kg, giving a replenishment rate of 1.15e10 m^3/s; each square meter needs to vent 22 milliliters of Radon gas per second.

The [decay chain](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a1/Decay_chain%284n%2B2%2C_Uranium_series%29.PNG) of Radon-222 involves many tasty heavy metals and eventually ends in Lead-206, which will accumulate at 1.34e11 kg/s, or 2.63e-4 kg/s per m^2; lead dust will sediment at 2.31e-8 m/s = 2 mm/day or 0.73 m/year.

The decay chain starts at U-238, which has a half-life time of 4.5 billion years. To produce 1.45e11 kg/s of Radon-222 would require 3.16e28 kg of U-238 -- 3.1e4 times the mass of your planet, so... U-238 cannot be the origin of the Radon.

The next-longest-lived element of the decay chain is U-234 with a half-life time of 245k years, you'd need 1.70e24 kg of that -- still heavier than the planet.

The next option is Thorium-230, with a half-life time of 75k years. We'd need just 5.14e23 kg of it, or 51 % of the mass of the planet. As a bonus, its density is around 1.17e4 kg/m^3, very close to the density of the planet. Of course, this means that the planet must be very young - at most 75k years old, and its radon production will greatly reduce in the next tens of thousands of years.

Finally, decay heat. Over the entire decay chain from Th-230 to Pb-206, a fraction of 1.87e-4 of the mass is released as energy. Some of that will be carried away by neutrinos, but must will heat the planet (inside or in the atmosphere).

This is a mass-energy conversion rate of 2.81e7 kg/s or 2.52e24 W, or 0.66 % the power output of the sun. Per area, it's 4.93e9 W/m^2. Earth provides around 8.2e-2 W/m^2.

Assuming a perfect black body, this means the surface temperature of your planet is 1.72e4 K (T^4 ~ P/A). Of course, this means that the planet will be made entirely of plasma, and evaporate quickly, so unfortunately your idea looks impossible.

**However**, Radon is a very heavy gas, heavy enough not to mix with the atmosphere too much. On Earth, it likes to accumulate in basements. Conceivably, if your planet has no wind for some reason, Radon might accumulate in the very lowest layers of the atmosphere, maybe just in the lowest 2 meters. If you limited yourself to that, you'd need **much less** radon, which would mean less heat, less accumulation of lead dust and fewer geothermal vents. Just scale all of the numbers down accordingly - except for temperature. Due to Boltzmann's law, if you reduce the amount of radon 10000x, you can only reduce temperature 10x.

If you're happy with a still-extremely-deadly* 1 ppm of Radon instead of 8.3%, and just confined to the lowest 1/1000th (by mass) of the atmosphere, your planet will be somewhere around room temperature. You could even go for the longer-lived U-238 as source material. You should move the planet well away from the parent star to avoid any extra heating.

*) 1 ppm of Radon at 1.3 atm has an activity of 1.94 Ci/L, a comfortable 4.9e11 times the EPA action limit.

If you really want a radioactive gas that makes up a single-digit percentage of the atmosphere, may I interest you in some other gasses, like H-3? Kr-81? Ar-39?

I also hear that [Unobtainium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtainium), a recently-discovered element in the [Island of stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_stability), has a density and half-life similar to that of U-238 while decaying directly into a gas that has properties that happen to be exactly right for your story. It is theorized to be formed in great quantities in a certain type of supernova, which explains why there's none of it on Earth but elsewhere entire planets are made of it.

Comment: Note on methods: I pulled most data from Wikipedia or Wolfram alpha. For decay rates I multiplied the "decay constant" value (sort of an inverted half-life) with the mass of the material. To produce 222 kg of Rn-222, you need 226 kg of Ra-226, so I multiplied with mass ratios as needed. For decay heat, I calculated the difference of the atomic masses of (Source Isotope - Target Isotope - He4 particles), followed by E=mc².